# Does std::move always work as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11

As I know `std::move` (same as `static_cast<T&&>`) casts variable to rvalue and assigns to lvalue, and because of this I think in following code:

```
int a = 1;
int b = static_cast<int&&>(a);
```

`b` and `a` have the same address, but in VS, it prints different addresses.

```
int a = 1;
int b = static_cast<int&&>(a);
cout << hex << &a << endl;
cout << hex << &b << endl;
```

If after this `a` still points to a different memory location, what is the benefit of using `std::move` in this case?

Comment: `a` and `b` are distinct objects, so they cannot have the same address. That has nothing to do with `std::move`.

Comment: And yes, it *always* works as expected, if your expectations are correct :-)

Comment: But `static_cast<T&&>` is `std::forward<T>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because you "move" them doesn't mean they will share the same address. Moving a value is a high level abstraction, with basic types like `int` moving and copying is completely the same, which is happening here. I suggest you read  the [excellent post on std::move](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/1870760) to know what it does and what it's uses are.

Answer (score 2):

No, `b` is its own object, which is *copy initialized* from an rvalue reference to another int. This is the same as just copying the referenced object.

Move semantics only shines when the "copying" can be preformed by resource stealing (since we know the other objects storage is about to go, anyway).

For a type like an integer, it's still a plain copy.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `std::move` in `C++` you do **not** *move* the object itself, you *move* the **value** of the object or its *contents*. So its address does not change.

Moving is no different from copying with an `int`. But for a complex type with internal pointers to allocated memory, that memory can be transferred *without* copying using a `std::move` (assuming it has been designed to respond to `std::move`).

Comment: Isn't `std::move` just a `static_cast`, so it doesn't actually move anything by itself?

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted. Imho it helps to think of move as not moving the instance itself but its contents. The fact that `std::move` actually does not move anything is just a quirk of the language, but still most of the time when calling `std::move` one is actually moving something.

Comment: @Rakete1111 The language rules trigger a *move* operation if you make that cast (move construct or assign). So the way you *move* things in `C++` is to use the expression `std::move`. So no, `std::move` does not actually move anything by itself but the compiler does when you use `std::move` (assuming you use it on an object designed to be moved).

Comment: @Galik The language doesn't trigger a "move operation". The library implementor does.

Comment: @juanchopanza Respectfully disagree. The library implementer presents the compiler with the facility to either move or copy, the compiler decides which facility to employ based on language rules and the programmer forces the compiler to choose move by using the cast `std::move`.

Comment: The language doesn't have any "move operation".

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't believe I said it did. I said it *triggers* a move operation which the library designer may or may not have facilitated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit of using std::move on an int. In your example you are basically copying the value from a to b.

Move semantics is only meaningfull on resources where you want to transfer ownership, e.g. dynamically allocated memory. Take the  std::unique_ptr as an example.

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<int>(1);
auto ptrCopy = ptr;     // copy will not work compilation error.       
auto ptrMove = std::move(ptr);
```

In the above example ptrMove has taken over the ownership of ptr and ptr is now empty.

Comment: Not just memory. All resources can be meaningfully moved. Open files, connections, unique_locks, opaque handles …